# Fetch some data when user enters some other data

Tags: forms

I have a popup dialog like this:

[image: Popup dialog]

- Red and green sections are editable but the blue one is read-only
- Blue section content is fetched from the IP and port previously entered by user
- Green section is entered by user according to the content of blue section

Now I wonder:

- Is there a better UI/UX design for what I intend to do?
- When to fetch `Available IDs` according to IP and port? For example, when users finishes editing IP and port?
- Is it more preferable to develop a button for fetching IDs by user click?

Comment: @GrecKo If so, feel free to migrate it over there =)

Comment: I can't, only a moderator can

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the blue section should appear automatically after filling the green and red ones.

in the context of IP and port, I think it is worth using validation (as for the ip format - is it 4 or 6?):

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/program-to-validate-an-ip-address/

Inform the user about the correct or incorrect address based on the defined format (green and red (possibilities - red border, icon, message under the input))

Identically with the port, additionally using the condition that if ip and the port are properly validated then you can run the function responsible for displaying Available IDs

Comment: I implemented these: (1) verify IP and port with regular expressions (2) automatically fetch IDs when user enters IP and port (3) develop a button to fetch IDs on demand, just in case user intends to do so

Comment: I am not convinced whethera button on demand is necessary just in case? can anyone comment on this matter?